# POST em Ajax chega com dados nulos no ActionResult do MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma função em AJAX que é o evento `click` de um botão onde pego todos os `checkbox` que estao checados e pego o values de cada um e jogo em um array desta forma:

```js
$("#btnDropMessageSents").click(function (e) {

    var ids = [];

    $("#inbox-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        if (this.checked === true) {
            ids.push($(this).val());
        }
    }); 


    if (ids.length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Inbox/DeleteDefinitive',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: values = [{ 'values': '1006' }, { 'values': '1005' }, { 'values': '1004' }],
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Na linha `data: values` eu coloquei valores na mão mesmo para ver se daria certo mesmo assim não foi.

Já minha `ActionResult` na controller está assim:

```asp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteDefinitive(string[] values)
{
    var MensagemEnviadaDomain = new MensagemEnviada();
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        var Model = MensagemEnviadaDomain.GetItem(_ => _.COD_MENSAGEM == Convert.ToInt32(item));
        MensagemEnviadaDomain.Edit(new MensagemEnviadaDto()
        {
            COD_MENSAGEM = Model.COD_MENSAGEM,
            COD_AUTOR = Model.COD_AUTOR,
            COD_REMETENTE = Model.COD_REMETENTE,
            ID = Model.ID,
            STATUS_AUTOR = Model.STATUS_AUTOR,
            STATUS_REMETENTE = "E",
        });
    }

    return (RedirectToAction("Sent", "Inbox"));
}
```

Já tentei de inumeras vezes e formas diferentes na minha função em AJAX não sei o que possa ser mas o erro que dá é sempre o mesmo :

> Erro 500 Internal Server Erro

mas esse erro se dá por que meu array de `values` chega vazio ou seja como `null` na action... Como consertar isso?

Comment: Oi, Rodrigo, por favor confira se o título descreve exatamente o problema, dizer "problema com X" podia ser o título das 30 mil perguntas do site :) O ideal é descrever breve e exatamente do que se trata. A formatação de código com o Stack Snippets é só para HTML+CSS+JS que pode ser executado, senão use a formatação simples: botão `{ }` do editor.

Answer (score 0):

Esa forma de pasar os o data para a funcao ajax poderia estar provocando, pois debbugando no console da undefine.

Tente da seguinte maneira

```
data: {'values':[{ 'values': '1006' }, { 'values': '1005' }, { 'values': '1004' }]},
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu faco a coisa um pouco mais simples:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteDefinitive(List<string> dataList)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        success = true,
        count = dataList.Count(),
        items = string.Join(",", dataList)
    });
}
```

a minha View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "StackOverflow";
}

<form>
    <ul>
        @for (var i = 1000; i < 1010; i++)
        {
            <li>
                <label for="chk_@i">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_@i" name="chk" value="@i"/> @i
                </label>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
</form>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(".button").click(function () {

            var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteDefinitive", "Home")',
                dta = [];

            $("input[name=chk][type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                dta.push($(this).val());
            });

            $.post(url, { dataList: dta }, function (data) {
                alert("total: " + data.count + "\n values: " + data.items);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]